# Create a new sheet and hyperlink the sheet in the summary sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed a code to copy a sheet and rename the sheet name with the value given in the insert box and then copy the same value in the summary sheet and select the last cell and paste the value but I want to create the hyperlink so that if i click on that value it will take me to that sheet.

I am stuck at the giving the proper subaddress.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sName As String
    Dim oRng As Range

    sName = InputBox("New Shipment", "New AWB Number", "Enter the AWB Number")

    If sName <> "" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templete").Copy Before:=Sheets(3)  
        ActiveSheet.Name = sName
        MsgBox "New AWB Number Tracking Added"
    Else
        MsgBox "Failed"  
    End If

    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Activate

    ActiveCell.Value = sName
    'ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "'Sheet(3)'!A1"
End Sub
```

When I run this I am getting an error:

> "Reference isn't valid"

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always run into issues when using `Select` and `Activate` but I suspect your main issue was your hyperlink sub address. You where trying to set it to `'Sheet(3)'!A1"` which excel won't recognise as it is the sheet position (which VBA recognises) rather than the sheet name. Have a look at the below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sName As String
    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim nWs As Worksheet

    sName = InputBox("New Shipment", "New AWB Number", "Enter the AWB Number")

    If sName <> "" Then
        With ThisWorkbook
            .Sheets("Templete").Copy Before:=.Sheets(3)
            Set nWs = .Sheets(3)
        End With
        nWs.Name = sName

        With Sheets("Summary")
            With .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                .Value2 = sName
                .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                                        "'" & nWs.Name & "'!A1"
            End With
        End With

        MsgBox "New AWB Number Tracking Added"
    Else
        MsgBox "Failed"
    End If
End Sub
```

You should probably also add to this a check to test against existing sheets for duplicate or invalid names entered by the user.